# Python Popen stderr catch output

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, stderr

I am running a command via Popen and catching the stderr and using that to update a display elsewhere, this is working correctly, updating every time stderr outputs something, but I am also trying to save the output to a log file in realtime. While this does write the output to a file, it doesn't seem to update this file very often. Is there a way I get get the output writing to the file every time there is something to write?
Here is the code:

```
self.process1 = Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
logFile = open(logFilePath, "a")
while True:
    line222 = self.process1.stderr.readline().decode('utf-8')
    logFile.write(line222)
```

Comment: I think `logFile.flush()` immediately after `logfFile.write()` will make the work

Comment: And also there is a method of `Popen`, which I currently can't remember, that you can use as the condition to the `while` loop and that will give you the output line by line... Need to check in the docs

Comment: logFile.flush()  works a treat, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in iter(self.process1.stderr.readline,b""):
    line222 = line.decode('utf-8')
    logFile.write(line222)
    logFile.flush()
```

Comment: the code is broken. If it is Python 2 then `logFile.write(line.decode('utf-8'))` breaks because `logFile` writes `str` type, not `unicode` (an exception on first non-ascii character). If it is Python 3 then `iter(self.process1.stderr.readline,""):` never stops because `'' != b''` there.

Comment: The buffering doesn't matter if you pass the file to `stderr` (only `logfile.fileno()` is used). Also, OP wants both to capture stderr (*"every time stderr outputs something"*) *and* to save it to a file.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian,  I presumed the OP was using python3 because of `decode('utf-8')` I just forgot the `b`. I am not sure I understand the point about stderr, I don't see that anywhere in the OP's code.

Comment: If OP uses Python 3 then use `for line in self.process1.stderr:` instead -- you don't need `iter()` here as I've mentioned in my answer. To understand the point about stderr, [look at the revision of your answer that my comment refers to](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7d423e7c-84af-41ac-b3fe-89b8c0682879/view-source).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, are you talking about the fact I did not assign the variable `line222 = line.decode('utf-8')`?  I presume you don't need `iter` in your answer either then?

Comment: No. I'm not. My answer works on both Python 2/3 and therefore it needs `iter()`. Google "Python read-ahead bug".

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, so `iter` with a sentinel of `" "` will work on both python 2 and 3?

Comment: It will *in my code* because I use `universal_newlines=True` that enables *text mode*.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, is there any downside to using `universal_newlines=True`?

Comment: `universal_newlines` is implemented using `io.TextIOWrapper` that has Python implementation that you could look at. Everything has a downside.  Even [by fixing a bug; you could break somebody's workflow](http://xkcd.com/1172/)

Answer (score 0):

By default, files use a block-buffering i.e., nothing is written to disk until the buffers overflow. Block size is typically 4K or 8K bytes.

In your case, It  should be enough to make the file line-buffered:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo, 
          stderr=PIPE, bufsize=1,  # `1` means line-buffered (our end)
          universal_newlines=True) # convert to text, normalize newlines
with p.stderr, open(log_filename, "a", 1) as log_file: # `1` means line-buffered
    for line in iter(p.stderr.readline, ''):
        for file in [sys.stderr, log_file]:
            print(line, end='', file=file)
p.wait()
```

If you are on Python 3 then you don't need `iter()` here (the read-ahead bug is fixed there); you could use just  `for line in pipe:` instead.

I assume that you've used `utf-8` as a place-holder for user's locale character encoding.